# Plotting non continuous data in Grafana

Tags: grafana

I am using InfluxDB as the backend source which stores OHLC data for stocks. 
Now the market is not open all the time and hence when I am plotting the data there are missing areas.

I want to have a continuous graph, something like where I can define the market timings so that the graph is one continuous line.

Here is what is currently rendered:

[image]

Comment: Seems like the point values between "market close" and "open" can have  difference. So how should the `straight` line look like? For instance if the closing point is lower than opening then it will need to have '/' upwards straight line?

Comment: @SamuelToh Yes, that won't be a problem. That's how stock charting apps plot.

Comment: maybe you can try doing `fill(linear)` this means that when influxdb encounters a missing point, it will perform linear interpolation to draw a '/', '-' or '\' line to the next line. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @SamuelToh Thanks. This is better than what was before. Is there a way to remove points from the x label for which no data is available? I noticed that this is how tradingview and other programs work.

Comment: Sorry didn't quite get what you meant. x-label as in the x-axis? Maybe use paint or something to draw the expected output on the image you have above so I can better understand your second question. Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

**Q:** I want to have a continuous graph, something like where I can define the market timings so that the graph is one continuous line.

**A:** As discussed in the comment. Use `fill(linear)` operation to substitute the missing points with interpolated points. In this case `linear` means linear interpolation.

That is, when `influxdb` encounters a missing point, it will perform linear interpolation to draw a straight line to the next available point. So you get one of the three lines - '/', '-' or '\'.

Comment: I tried A and it worked. However, how most of the trading plots work is that they don't have the points on the x-axis for which there is no corresponding y-value. fill(linear) is much better solution than what I had before but is there a way to instruct grafana to leave those points(dates) on the x-axis for which no value is returned?

Comment: You can't do that in Grafana. Ok. I think I know what you meant here. What you could is to use `Kapacitor` to pre-process the missing points that falls within the period where the market is open and have them fill the value as `0` that way the `fill linear` will not be applied to those points. Unfortunately there is a steep learning curve for `Kapacitor`, so if you can write a simple app to manually fill the missing points with value = 0 that could be an easier way out.